# Clearing leaked memory from JNA loaded library

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jna

I have to work with a library which was designed to be run once, output a file, and move on.  I need to use it in a streamlined fashion as data for my Java program.  After a few iterations of my custom driver, I noticed it was having a massive performance drop off, so I started unloading the .so and reloading it.  (This is accomplished by setting the instance to null, and then requesting the gc -- not perfect, I know.)  This increased the operating speed drastically, but there are so many leaks on the inside that are not released when the library is unloaded, that it quickly leaks GB worth of data after just 200 iterations.

Is there any way at all, aside from trying to manipulate the inner workings of the driver, to clear the leaked memory?  Or is this impossible otherwise?

Comment: Run in a separate process and report results back to a master process.  After an acceptable number of iterations, restart the process.  You can use whatever IPC mechanism you feel comfortable with (including writing to a shared file).

Comment: Unfortunately, if the shared library is using `malloc/free`, then it's using up your process's heap memory, and there's no easy way to free it without actually tracking the memory yourself.